# IReport, Jasperserver: different result for the same report

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

My report based in this request:

```
select "Annee" ,"Diam", sum("Consommation") from "Consom_N","CptDim"
where "Annee" >= $P{a1} and "Annee" <= $P{a2} 
and "Consom_N"."NumCpt"="CptDim"."NumCpt"and "District"= $P{dst}
and $X{IN, cast("Diam" as character varying), DiamRQn}
group by "Annee","Diam"
order by "Annee"
;
```

"Diam" field is a smallint, the problem is in this part

```
$X{IN, cast("Diam" as character varying), DiamRQn}
```

DiamRQn is the parameter used by the control input wich is a multiple selection from request, 
when remove casting it says:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist : smallint = character varying
```

with casting it work fine in ireport preview , but on the jasperserver, the chart shows all the values of "Diam", the selected and the not selected. As i understood,for jasperserver, casted "diam" is always exist in "DiamRQn" collection, although everything went ok for ireport !

Additional inf:
DBMS: postgresql
ireport ver: 5.0.1

Comment: What is the parameter class of the `DiamRQn` parameter?

Comment: its java.util.Collection
i tried the class List and same result, also i tired this
 java.util.Collection<Short>
and no way

Comment: Make sure the parameter name is identical to the name of the input control.  It would probably throw an error if it was not, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Another thing you could do for testing is to put a text field on your report and set the expression to: `$P{DiamRQn}.toString()`.  That way you could see what the input control is passing to the report.

Comment: nice idea, i will try it, u r very helpfull Tom, thank you

Comment: in ireport it show the correct collection, in jasperserver it show "null" !!!  and DiamRQn request work fine in the DBMS !

Comment: So the value from the input control is not being passed properly to the parameter.  You may want to recreate the query list, then the input control and then maybe the parameter.  Double check the value field of the input control.  Then try again.  Sorry, I can't think of anything else at this point.

Comment: ok Tom, thank so much for all your advices

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems before performing functions with the $IN{} statement in Jasper.  My solution is usually to perform the function first, the doing the $IN{} statement after.  I usually do whatever function I need to do within a sub-select, and then do the $IN{} statement outside of it.  So you could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT "Annee" ,"Diam", sum("Consommation"),
       cast("Diam" as character varying) AS Diam_char
FROM   "Consom_N","CptDim"
WHERE  "Annee" >= $P{a1} and "Annee" <= $P{a2} 
       and "Consom_N"."NumCpt"="CptDim"."NumCpt" and "District"= $P{dst}
GROUP BY "Annee","Diam"
) x
WHERE  $X{IN, Diam_char, DiamRQn}
ORDER BY "Annee"
```

I would probably also move part of your where clause into a join between the Consom_N and CptDim tables, but that's optional.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT "Annee" ,"Diam", sum("Consommation"),
        cast("Diam" as character varying) AS Diam_char 
FROM   "Consom_N"
       JOIN "CptDim" ON "Consom_N"."NumCpt"="CptDim"."NumCpt" 
WHERE  "Annee" >= $P{a1} and "Annee" <= $P{a2} 
       and "District"= $P{dst}
GROUP BY "Annee","Diam"
) x
WHERE  $X{IN, Diam_char, DiamRQn}
ORDER BY "Annee"
```

Comment: Same problem !
Thank you a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the input control is returning values of type varchar (char varying).  Is it possible to change the query/list source of the input control to return values of type smallint?  Then perhaps you could remove the `CAST` function and hopefully all would be well.

Comment: Thank you Tom, but i have tried it, and now i have altered the data type of the field in the db source, and fail again !
Thank you so much

Comment: Do you get an error?  Or does it just not filter the results?

Comment: No error, it doesnt filter results
the picture is attached in this post, plz take a look
[link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/815662/collection-parameter-problem-x)